# Assume $X_1,...,X_n$, are i.i.d, $E(X^k)=\mu_k, k=3,4$ Then sample variance satisfies $\sqrt{n}(\hat\sigma^2-\sigma^2)\to_D N(0,\alpha^2)$

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

> Assume $X_1,...,X_n$, are i.i.d,  $E(X_i)=\mu, Var(X_i) = \sigma^2, E(X^k)=\mu_k, k=3,4$ Then sample variance satisfies $\sqrt{n}(\hat\sigma^2-\sigma^2)\to_D N(0,\alpha^2)$, find $\alpha$

the question doesnt say but I assume it means sample variance $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar X)^2$, not divided by $n-1$.

So Central Limit Theorem gives me that $\sqrt{n}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \mu)\to_D N(0,\Sigma)$

And so from here I want to use delta method, to find some function $f$, to take $f(\bar X)-f(\mu)=\hat\sigma^2-\sigma^2$
and then use the delta method to compute $\alpha$

I expanded $\hat\sigma^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i^2 - 2X_i \bar X +\bar X^2)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \bar X^2$

I know that $\sigma^2=E(X^2)-\mu^2$

From here I'm not sure what to do, I also don't see where the condition that $E(X^k)=\mu_k, k=3,4$ would be needed.

Comment: What's $\mu_k$?

Comment: @DanielP $k$th moment

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but saying "the $k$th moment equals the $k$th moment" is not too informative! :P

Comment: @DanielP I think OP is trying to say the kth moments are given (up to k=4) and presumably are finite, and these givens are just assigned those labels

Comment: Ah, they're finite! Right, that *is* a meaningful condition.

Comment: Also, the title is slightly incorrect, I think one of those $\sigma$'s is supposed to have a hat.

Comment: @DanielP I fixed the title, and yes I think them being finite is needed for a use of CLT but I don't really see why I would actually need the 3rd and 4th moment inparticular.

Comment: @AColoredReptile classical CLT  needs finite second moments of whatever is being averaged. In this case, $X_i^2$ is being averaged so you need finite second moment of $X_i^2$, i.e. finite fourth moment of $X_i$.

Comment: Seems your question has been answered here already: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105337/asymptotic-distribution-of-sample-variance-of-non-normal-sample

With $\alpha = \mu_4 - \sigma^4$. This is why $\mu_4$ needed to exist.

Comment: @AColoredReptile If you search asymptotic distribution of sample variance, you are sure to find what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sketch for how to approach this:

Multivariate CLT tells us

$$W_i\equiv(X_i,X_i^2)'\text{ iid}\implies \sqrt n (\frac{1}{n}\sum_i W_i-E[W_1])\to_d N(0,V(W_1)).$$

Note how the finite moment assumptions are used in the above!

Now write

$$\sqrt n(\hat \sigma^2-\sigma^2)=\sqrt n \left(g\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_i W_i\right)-g\left(E[W_1]\right)\right)$$

where
$$g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}, g(a,b)=b-a^2$$
and use delta method.

Comment: I don't see how $g$ would act on $\bar W$ though, its not linear right?

Comment: @AColoredReptile Correct it is nonlinear. Delta method works for any differentiable function

Comment: @AColoredReptile If it helps, write $\bar W=(\frac{1}{n} \sum_i X_i, \frac{1}{n} \sum_i X_i^2)'$